# Is there a function in pandas to do this composite time-indexed merge operation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have dataframes looking like this,

df1 :

```
                          X1   X2   X3    X4
2021-02-23 15:44:20.100  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.300  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.500  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.700  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.900  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:21.100  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:21.300  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:21.500  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:21.700  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:21.900  NaN    0    1   Nan
```

df2 :

```
                          X1   X2   X3    X4
2021-02-23 15:44:20.000    0    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.200    3    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.400  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.600  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.800  NaN    0    1     3
2021-02-23 15:44:21.000  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:21.200  NaN    0    1     3
2021-02-23 15:44:21.400  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:21.600  NaN    0    1     4
2021-02-23 15:44:21.800  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:22.000  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:22.200  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:22.400  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:22.600  NaN    0    1   Nan
```

I want to perform a merge/join/concatenate operation on the values from columns of the left DataFrame (df1) to the Right Dataframe (df2). This would be searching for a row wise timedelta in the time index and replacing NaNs which might already be there...

Intuition: Kinda like a merge_asof but not creating _x and _y columns, instead replacing the values from the left df to the right.

Please note:

- The columns in the right dataframe are always exactly equal to the columns on the left dataframe.
- In the intuition.. `pandas.Dataframe.merge_asof()` does a left join but my case is different it is more like an outer join.

Resulting joined/merged DataFrame:

```
                          X1   X2   X3    X4
2021-02-23 15:44:20.100    0    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.300    3    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.500  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.700  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:20.900  NaN    0    1     3
2021-02-23 15:44:21.100  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:21.300  NaN    0    1     3
2021-02-23 15:44:21.500  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:21.700  NaN    0    1     4
2021-02-23 15:44:21.900  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:22.000  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:22.200  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:22.400  NaN    0    1   Nan
2021-02-23 15:44:22.600  NaN    0    1   Nan
```

### What I have tried:

1. One method i tried is to resample the df1 and df2 with the frequency set as 'T' which basically ensures both the data-frames would have same keys if any. Then performing joins would be straight forward.

- Problem: Downsampling a df in pandas drops NaN rows by default and i am not aware of a technique to prevent it. I do not want to drop any data.. just replace.

2. merge_asof or traditional merges create duplicate columns with suffixes, which i do not want.
3. join and append just adds the rows of the df2 to df1 which is also not what i want.

### What i propose might work:

1. checking the second Dataframe manually for a row mathcing the timedelta and iterate over every row. This also is infeasible in my case as the dataframes in question are very large.

```
df1.shape -> (12200317 rows x 41 columns)
df2.shape -> (10000023 rows x 41 columns)
```

I also have multiple dataframes to go through. (approximately 50)

If there are any duplicates of this question .. I couldn't find one..
Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: None of the index timestamp labels in df1 match df2. Can you provide a more minimalist, reproducible example, with a minimum set of column and minimum set of rows and describe the input and output you want.

Comment: "None of the index timestamp labels in df1 match df2" Yes, that is kind'a the point of the question. This is  a minimal example with set of columns and rows defined, and the output is also given. The question is then how to "reproduce" what is there as output programatically using pandas. Did i misunderstand your coment? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: a minimal example would not have a dataframe with an index of length 14, nor do you need 4 columns. A reproducible example would contain the code necessary for constructing your minimal dataframes. your resulting dataframe as stated is the same as df2 so that cannot be your intended result. Apologise if I completely miss the point, but if I do, I suspect so do many others.

Comment: "a minimal example would not have a dataframe with an index of length 14, nor do you need 4 columns."? Ok. 
"your resulting dataframe as stated is the same as df2 so that cannot be your intended result"- No, it is not.
"Apologise if I completely miss the point" You are, IMO